# Change Public GKE to Private GKE cluster using terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

How to change the existing GKE cluster to GKE private cluster? Will I be able to connect to the Kubectl API from internet based on firewall rules or should I have a bastion host? I don't want to implement `Cloud Nat` or `nat gateway`. I have a  squid proxy VM that can handle internet access for pods. I just need to be able to connect to Kubectl to apply or modify anything.

I'm unsure how to modify the existing module I wrote to make the nodes private and I'm not sure if the cluster will get deleted if I try and apply the new changes related to private gke cluster.

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name     = "prod"
  network  = "prod"
  subnetwork = "private-subnet-a"
  location               = "us-west1-a"
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count = 1

  depends_on = [var.depends_on_vpc]
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_nodes" {
  depends_on = [var.depends_on_vpc]

  name       = "prod-node-pool"
  location   = "us-west1-a"
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.primary.name
  node_count = 2

  node_config {
    preemptible  = false
    machine_type = "n1-standard-2"

    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true"
    }

    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the part of the question:

> How to change the existing GKE cluster to GKE private cluster?

[image: GKE Private cluster network settings]

**`GKE` setting: `Private cluster` is immutable.** This setting can only be set during the `GKE` cluster provisioning.

To create your cluster as a private one you can either:

- Create a new `GKE` private cluster.
- Duplicate existing cluster and set it to private:

  - This setting is available in `GCP Cloud Console` -> `Kubernetes Engine` -> `CLUSTER-NAME` -> `Duplicate`
  - This setting will clone the configuration of your infrastructure of your previous cluster but not the workload (`Pods`, `Deployments`, etc.)

> Will I be able to connect to the Kubectl API from internet based on firewall rules or should I have a bastion host?

Yes, you could but it will heavily depend on the configuration that you've chosen during the `GKE` cluster creation process.

As for ability to connect to your `GKE` private cluster, there is a dedicated documentation about it:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Private clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters)*

---

As for how you can create a private cluster with Terraform, there is the dedicated site with configuration options specific to `GKE`. There are also parameters responsible for provisioning a `private` cluster:

- *[Registry.terraform.io: Providers: Hashicorp: Google: Latest: Docs: Resources: Container cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster)*

As for a basic example of creating a private `GKE` cluster with Terraform:

- `main.tf`

```
provider "google" {
  project = "INSERT_PROJECT_HERE" 
  region  = "europe-west3"
  zone    = "europe-west3-c"
}
```

- `gke.tf`

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary-cluster" {
  name               = "gke-private"
  location           = "europe-west3-c"
  initial_node_count = 1

  private_cluster_config {
    enable_private_nodes = "true"
    enable_private_endpoint = "false" # this option will make your cluster available through public endpoint 
    master_ipv4_cidr_block = "172.16.0.0/28"
  }

  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name = "" 
    services_secondary_range_name = ""
  }

  
  node_config {
    machine_type = "e2-medium"
  }
}
```

> A side note!
>
> I've created a public `GKE` cluster, modified the `.tf` responsible for it's creation to support private cluster. After running: `$ terraform plan` **Terraform responded with the information that the cluster will be recreated**.

Comment: Testing it out atm. Creating a new cluster

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to recreate the cluster since the private/public option is immutable. Terraform will recreate the cluster.
2. To access the private cluster endpoints, you can choose [appropriate methods](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept#overview)

   ```
   1) Public endpoint access disabled:- creates a private cluster with no client access to the public endpoint.
   2) Public endpoint access enabled, authorized networks enabled:- creates a private cluster with limited access to the public endpoint.
   3) Public endpoint access enabled, authorized networks disabled:- creates a private cluster with unrestricted access to the public endpoint.
   ```
3. To ssh into the node/pod from the authorized network, you can setup access via [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding).

I am using [this terraform module](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine) to manage multiple clusters with the 2nd option, it is fully configurable.