# How can I disable SSH on nodes in a GKE node pool?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I am running a regional  GKE kubernetes cluster in is-central1-b us-central-1-c and us-central1-f. I am running 1.21.14-gke.700. I am adding a confidential node pool to the cluster with this command.

```
gcloud container node-pools create card-decrpyt-confidential-pool-1 \
--cluster=svcs-dev-1 \
--disk-size=100GB \
--disk-type=pd-standard \
--enable-autorepair \
--enable-autoupgrade \
--enable-gvnic \
--image-type=COS_CONTAINERD \
--machine-type="n2d-standard-2" \
--max-pods-per-node=8  \
--max-surge-upgrade=1 \
--max-unavailable-upgrade=1 \
--min-nodes=4 \
--node-locations=us-central1-b,us-central1-c,us-central1-f \
--node-taints=dedicatednode=card-decrypt:NoSchedule \
--node-version=1.21.14-gke.700 \
--num-nodes=4 \
--region=us-central1 \
--sandbox="type=gvisor" \
--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
--service-account="card-decrpyt-confidential@corp-dev-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
--shielded-integrity-monitoring \
--shielded-secure-boot \
--tags=testingdonotuse \
--workload-metadata=GKE_METADATA \
--enable-confidential-nodes
```

This creates a node pool but there is one problem... I can still SSH to the instances that the node pool creates. This is unacceptable for my use case as these node pools need to be as secure as possible. I went into my node pool and created a new machine template with ssh turned off using an instance template based off the one created for my node pool.

```
gcloud compute instance-templates create card-decrypt-instance-template \
--project=corp-dev-project
--machine-type=n2d-standard-2 
--network-interface=aliases=gke-svcs-dev-1-pods-10a0a3cd:/28,nic-type=GVNIC,subnet=corp-dev-project-private-subnet,no-address
 --metadata=block-project-ssh-keys=true,enable-oslogin=true 
--maintenance-policy=TERMINATE --provisioning-model=STANDARD 
--service-account=card-decrpyt-confidential@corp-dev-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform 
--region=us-central1 --min-cpu-platform=AMD\ Milan
 --tags=testingdonotuse,gke-svcs-dev-1-10a0a3cd-node 
--create-disk=auto-delete=yes,boot=yes,device-name=card-decrpy-instance-template,image=projects/confidential-vm-images/global/images/cos-89-16108-766-5,mode=rw,size=100,type=pd-standard 
--shielded-secure-boot 
--shielded-vtpm -
-shielded-integrity-monitoring 
--labels=component=gke,goog-gke-node=,team=platform --reservation-affinity=any
```

When I change the instance templates of the nodes in the node pool the new instances come online but they do not attach to the node pool. The cluster is always trying to repair itself and I can't change any settings until I delete all the nodes in the pool. I don't receive any errors.

What do I need to do to disable ssh into the node pool nodes with the original node pool I created or with the new instance template I created. I have tried a bunch of different configurations with a new node pool and the cluster and have not had any luck. I've tried different tags network configs and images. None of these have worked.

Other info:
The cluster was not originally a confidential cluster. The confidential nodes are the first of its kind added to the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed the metadata flag when creating the node pool
--metadata=block-project-ssh-keys=TRUE \

This blocked ssh.
However, enable-os-login=false won't work because it is reserved for use by the Kubernetes Engine

Comment: Interesting. This is not recommended for Kubernetes Nodes. ***VM Instances created by Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) are excluded from this recommendation due to differences in the available settings.*** https://www.trendmicro.com/cloudoneconformity/knowledge-base/gcp/ComputeEngine/enable-block-project-wide-ssh-keys.html

Comment: Does it say that anywhere in Google's documentation? It seems odd it would be documented there and not show up on google's docs.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I don't know the best practice here. Consider that just a link so that you have additional information. The issue about SSH is tricky because of dependencies on SSH and various methods of accessing systems via SSH.

Answer (score 1):

One option you have here is to enable private IP addresses for the nodes in your cluster. The [`--enable-private-nodes` flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create#--enable-private-nodes) will make it so the nodes in your cluster get *private* IP addresses (rather than the default public, internet-facing IP addresses).

Note that in this case, you would still be able to SSH into these nodes, but only from within your VPC network.

Also note that this means you would not be able to access `NodePort` type services from outside of your VPC network. Instead, you would need to use a `LoadBalancer` type service (or provide some other way to route traffic to your service from outside of the cluster, if required).

---

If you'd like to prevent SSH access even from within your VPC network, your easiest option would likely be to configure a firewall rule to deny SSH traffic to your nodes (TCP/UDP/SCTP port 22). Use network tags (the `--tags` flag) to target your GKE nodes.

Something along the lines of:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create fw-d-i-ssh-to-gke-nodes \
 --network NETWORK_NAME \
 --action deny \
 --direction ingress \
 --rules tcp:22,udp:22,sctp:22 \
 --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0 \
 --priority 65534 \
 --target-tags my-gke-node-network-tag
```

---

Finally, one last option I'll mention for creating a hardened GKE cluster is to use Google's [`safer-cluster`](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google/latest/submodules/safer-cluster) Terraform module. This is an opinionated setup of a GKE cluster that follows many of the principles laid out in Google's [cluster hardening guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster) and the Terraform module takes care of a lot of the nitty-gritty boilerplate here.

Comment: Can this be done without having to rebuild the existing cluster? This is the only node pool that needs to be private

Comment: As far as I know, no: the private cluster setting is immutable and can only be set at creation time. [This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65916344/change-public-gke-to-private-gke-cluster-using-terraform) discusses some approaches you could take. In short -- you can _duplicate_ the infrastructure config (node pools, etc.,) from your existing cluster and set the duplicate to be private. This won't duplicate your workloads though (Pods, Deployments, etc.,).